# Flutter web download a pdf from API and save in directory

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-web

I build a flutter web app and My requirement is to get a file(PDF) and write it in file or download it,
i get my file from an API and it gave me a file not a link,

Can anyone help me with this. An example would be more helpful.

Thank you

Comment: Yes we can help. But for that you need to share some piece of code that you already tried. A minimum reproducible example would be of huge help for us to help you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this utility method:

```
import 'dart:html' as html;

void openDownloadLink(String href, String filename) {
  html.document.createElement('a') as html.AnchorElement
    ..href = href
    ..download = filename
    ..dispatchEvent(html.Event.eventType('MouseEvent', 'click'));
}

Uri getHref() => Uri.parse(html.window.location.href);
```

The first parameter is the URL of the file to be downloaded, the second is the 'suggested' filename that the browser will show. Note that you can't put in a full path to the local file - the file name is just a suggestion.

The `getHref` function may be useful. It returns a `Uri` representing where the Flutter web app was launched from. If you want a path relative to that for your PDF, modify it, keeping the `https://server...` part the same. Equally, you could probably use a relative path as the `href` parameter, like `../pdfs/somefile`